# Explode and make array for every value

Tags: php, arrays, explode

I've tried to make this:

```
phones:[{"numbers":12345},{"numbers":67890}]
```

How can I achieve that from an explode?

```
$phones = "123456;7890
$phones = explode(';', $phones);
```

I've tried using `foreach` like this:

```
foreach($phones as $phone){
        $array["numbers"] = $phone;
}
```

But it keep replacing the first key. and yes i read that PHP array can't have the same key on an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're setting the `'numbers'` key in the array on each iteration. Instead, you want the result to be an array where every element is an associative array where the key is `'numbers'` and the value is a number:

```
$phones = "123456;7890";
$exploded = explode(';', $phones);
$result = array();
foreach ($exploded as $elem) {
    $result[] = array('numbers' => $elem);
}
```